# 415 unsupported media type on Postman

Tags: post, request, postman

I'm making a post request. I have raw body set to application/json I've also overriden the 'Accept' header from '*/*' value to 'application/json'. But I keep getting unsupported media type.[image]

[image]

Comment: At first glance, you have a duplicated `Accept` header, not sure how Postman behaves with that... could you try removing the `*/*`?

Comment: You can't remove it since it's auto-generated, but when I hover over it it says it is ignored since I added a custom duplicate

Comment: seems to be a postman specific error... from the terminal: `curl -XPOST "https://www.nyse.com/api/quotes/filter" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "filterToken": "", "maxResultsPerPage": 10, "sortOrder": "ASC"}'` works...

Comment: You can untick those auto gen headers, might also be would going to the settings of the request and disable the cookie jar option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was actually able to perform the request using the web postman... See here the headers:

[image]

And here the request/response:
[image]

I dont think so, but... Might it be the tabs in the body?

Comment: I removed the tabs and still the same. That's crazy you were able to, I'm even more confused now haha

Comment: Does it to the same @anuar if you recreated the whole thing in a new tab?