# How to upload a file to GCS bucket using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
I am new to GCP and I want to upload a pem file to a particular bucket using java sdk. I followed the below code.
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

// Create a bucket
String bucketName = "my_unique_bucket"; // Change this to something unique
Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));

// Upload a blob to the newly created bucket
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, "my_blob_name");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "a simple blob".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

But when i try to test this through postman i am getting 415 unsupported media type error.

```
Can any one help me with this.
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to use Google Cloud Storage from Java is to use the [Cloud Storage Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries).

Below sample code as an example of how to upload objects to Google Cloud Storage using the client library:

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Storage;
import com.google.cloud.storage.StorageOptions;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Blob;
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
import com.google.cloud.storage.BucketInfo;

// You need to Create your service object : 
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

// You need Create a bucket : 
String bucketName = "my_unique_bucket"; // Change this to something unique
Bucket bucket = storage.create(BucketInfo.of(bucketName));

// Upload a blob to the newly created bucket
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, "my_blob_name");
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).setContentType("text/plain").build();
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "a simple blob".getBytes(UTF_8));
```

Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51370070/19230181) Link for more information on file upload using Java.

for 415 unsupported media type errors : refer to these [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670413/unsupported-media-type-in-postman), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66248460/415-unsupported-media-type-on-postman) which helps you in resolving this concern.